# UDP Packet loss Fix

Tags: java, networking, udp

I implemented a Chat in Java with UDP. I have one thread that is sending the data of an array list to the other client and one thread receiving data from the other client. The array list can be filled with a method.

To send a message, a byte[] is picked out of the array list, its length is send and then the bytes are send.

Now i'm thinking about packet loss. How can I implement a fix for that? To send the message back would be very inefficent. I can send a message back, if the receiver didn't get the message, because i know the length of the message, but for that i will need a second socket at both clients cause receiver and sender are two threads. An other problem is what happens when the packet with the length of the data gets lost and the data package is read is length.

Can someone help me how to implement that?

(TCP is no solution cause i like to do UDP hole punching)

Comment: The fact that you like to do UDP hole punching isn't a reason not to use TCP, and the fact that there are two threads isn't a reason to require a second socket.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and well tested protocol for that called TCP. Because the only (relevant) difference between TCP and UDP is that TCP has correction for packet loss (and similar) and UDP does not.

That is why UDP should **only** be used if packet loss is irrelevant for the application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that doesn't help me. I need a soltuion for UDP because i'm doing UDP hole punching.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe work with sequence numbers. If a new message is generated, send that along with a sequence number. If the other peer detects a missing sequence number, it should try to request the missing messages from the other peer. Of course you should also be able to handle when a sequence number is simply no longer available or constantly fails by limiting the retries and using proper timeouts. Additionally the other peer could answer with "sequence number not available".

Essentially, this resembles what TCP does for you. So looking at how TCP handles reliable packet transmission will help you in finding a solution for your use-case.

Simplified, TCP solves this by keeping packets in a buffer: Packets are removed from the buffer if the other peer acknowledged the reception. The other peer can request to resend the buffer if it detects missing packets. To detect this, the receiver also uses a buffer. If buffers are full, packet transmission is paused. That's why you need bigger buffers to keep the pipeline of long-delay high-speed links (like satellite links) full and utilize the link at max throughput. Since this is not what you need, and since your only handle single messages, you can simplify that: Your buffer is the complete chat history with a sequence counter kept in sync, and you don't need throughput, just reliable transmission.